# Google Chrome automatic login

Tags: google-chrome

For a while, I remember having a really nice automatic login feature from Google Chrome on Google websites. It was a little yellow bar that would pop up and prompt me, "Sign in as ______". Now I'm on Beta, and I don't have this thing anymore.

Is there a flag or another way to enable this?